# Flickering on hover with mousemove

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, mousemove

I'm attempting to build a hover effect inspired by [golden-spike.com](http://www.golden-spike.com/) (and adapting their code, actually). Having some trouble, though, since their code uses a negative z-index, which I cannot use because I need there to be a background color on the page.

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tNms9/416/). You'll notice if you change the z-index on the .show_img class to -1 the flickering disappears completely.

Here's the Javascript I'm currently using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var mouseX;
var mouseY;
$(".title").mousemove( function(e) {
   mouseX = e.clientX; 
   mouseY = e.clientY;
});  
$(".title").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).next(".show_img").css("visibility","visible");
    $(window).bind('mousemove', function(e){
        $(".title").next(".show_img").css({'top':mouseY,'left':mouseX});
    });
  },
  function () {
    $(".show_img").css("visibility","hidden");

  });
});
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try positioning the image a little further from the cursor

```
mouseX = e.clientX + 5; 
mouseY = e.clientY + 5;
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tNms9/433/)

The problem was that the hover event triggered an image that covered the text being hovered.

Comment: I was positioning an SVG image using `mouseenter` and `mousemove` events and this comment made clear why I was seeing flicker; the image appearing under the cursor was causing an event loop. I solved the looping problem by applying CSS `pointer-events: none` to the image.

Answer (score 0):

The mouse move event gets captured by the image element which turns the hover off and if it bubbles up to the title it's fired again:

Try:

```
$(".title").next(".show_img").css({'top':mouseY+10,'left':mouseX+10});
```

**DEMO**
http://jsfiddle.net/tNms9/423/